# Show that if $G$ is free abelian with basis $\{x, y\}$, show that $\{2x+3y, x+y\}$ is also a basis for $G$

Tags: algebraic-topology, free-groups, free-abelian-group

This is from Munkres' Section 67, but there is a typo in the original question which is as follows:

> Show that if $G$ is free abelian with basis $\{x, y\}$, show that $\{2x+3y, x-y\}$ is also a basis for $G$.

This is indeed a typo and has been disucssed here: [Let $x$ , $y$ be the basis of a free abelian group of rank 2, prove that $2x+3y$ and $ x-y$ generate a free subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211625/let-x-y-be-the-basis-of-a-free-abelian-group-of-rank-2-prove-that-2x3y)

However, this link https://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-11/section-67-direct-sums-of-abelian-groups/problem-3-solution/ gives an alternative version, which he claims doable:

> Show that if $G$ is free abelian with basis $\{x, y\}$, show that $\{2x+3y, x+y\}$ is also a basis for $G$.

However, I did not follow the proof given in this link.

$2x+3y$ and $x+y$ are clearly independent, since if $$A(2x+3y)+B(x+y)=0,$$ then we have $$(2A+B)x+(3A+B)y=0,$$ since $\{x,y\}$ is a basis, we must have $2A+B=0$ and $3A+B=0$, which implies $A=B=0$.

Thus, $\{2x+3y, x+y\}$ clearly generates a group with them as basis.

**However, how could I show this group generated by them is indeed $G$?**

I tried to identify $g=AX+BY=C(2X+3Y)+D(X-Y)$ for $g\in G$, and in the end I have $A=2C+D$ and $B=3C-D$, but it seems that the link suggest another set of solutions, but I don't really understand where it comes from..

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: You are looking for integers $A$ and $B$ such that $A(2x+3y) + B(x+y) = x$ and similarly for $y$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang oh! got you. Let me work on it

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I get $A=-1$, $B=3$ for $x$ and $A=1/2$, $B=-1$ for $y$. and thus they generates another basis so generates $G$, Thank you so much! Do you want to post an answer? Only copying your comment will be perfect :)

Comment: OK, I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u=2x+3y$ and $v=x+y$.  You want to show that $u$ and $v$ generate $G$.  It suffices to show that there exist integers $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ such that 
\begin{align*}
    Au + Bv &= x &\implies A(2x+3y) + B(x+y) &= x &\implies (2A+B)x + (3A+B)y &= x\\
    Cu + Dv &= y &\implies C(2x+3y) + D(x+y) &= y &\implies (2C+D)x + (3C+D)y &= y\\
\end{align*}
The first line gives equations
\begin{align*}
    2A+B &= 1 \\
    3A+B &= 0
\end{align*}
Apparently $A=-1$ and $B=3$ satisfy the system.
The second line gives equations
\begin{align*}
    2C+D &= 0 \\
    3C+D &= 1
\end{align*}
This time $C=1$ and $D=-2$ work.

What's really going on here is that the matrix which expresses $u$ and $v$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ is invertible over $\mathbb{Z}$:
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}u \\ v \end{bmatrix}
    = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}
\implies
    \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}
    = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
    \begin{bmatrix}u \\ v \end{bmatrix}
    = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 3 \\ 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}u \\ v \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: The last sentence says it all.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am sorry for my computation error.